# Linearize ODE given by $x'=x^2+y^2-4$, $y'=x^2-y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Linearize ODE given by $x'=x^2+y^2-4$, $y'=x^2-y^2$

Find all critical points, find the linearization at each critical point.

So I computed the jacobian matrix, $\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\2&-2\\\end{pmatrix}$

Then I found the eigenvalues to be $2\sqrt{2},-2\sqrt{2}$

For a critical point I need $x'(x,y)=0$ and $y'(x,y)=0$

$x^2-y^2=0$, then $x^2=y^2$ then $x^2+y^2-4=x^4-4=0$, so $x^2=2$

So I believe then the critical points are $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}),(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$

Do I know these are all critical points?

And then my linearization of the critical points is just $Jx$?

Comment: $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}),(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ are also critical points.

Comment: @mfl To find the linearization at each critical point do I just multiply the matrix I have by that point or is their a simpler way to find all the corresponding eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linearization of the system $$\left\{ \begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,y)\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y)\end{align}\right.$$ at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$\left\{ \begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt}=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=g(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)\end{align}\right.$$ Thus, if $(x_0,y_0)=(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$ it is

$$\left\{ \begin{align} \frac{dx}{dt}=2\sqrt 2(x-\sqrt 2)+2\sqrt 2(y-\sqrt 2)\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=2\sqrt 2(x-\sqrt 2)-2\sqrt 2(y-\sqrt 2)\end{align}\right.$$